# Removing all attributes from a table

Tags: c#, html, css, .net, anglesharp

I want to have a standard table without any attributes. But I have got a table that's exported from a program called QlikView in there they automatically give the table attributes, weirdly too. Is there a fast way to remove all these attributes, I'm using .NET Core and I haven't found any. I want to do this so that I can use my own CSS easily. Here is the HTML I'm getting when exporting:

````html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META CONTENT="StraightTableBox">
<TITLE>TM_SW_0004 Resultaten overzicht dekweken</TITLE>
<SCRIPT> function UpdateImage(name) { var img = document.getElementById(name); var url = '' + document.location; url = url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf('/')+1); img.src = url + name; }</SCRIPT></HEAD>
<BODY CLASS="std" BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<!--StartFragment-->

<BR>
<TABLE style="font-size:9pt;"  border="1" bordercolor="#C0C0C0"  CELLSPACING=0  CELLPADDING=2 bgcolor="#ffffff">
<TR BGCOLOR="#000084"><TD COLSPAN=11>
<FONT style="font-size:11pt"><FONT COLOR="white"><B>TM_SW_0004 Resultaten overzicht dekweken</B></FONT></FONT></TR>

<TR BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5" ALIGN=CENTER> <TH ALIGN=LEFT NOWRAP><FONT COLOR="#363636"><B>Belegungswoche<B></B></FONT> <TH NOWRAP><FONT COLOR="#363636"><B>belegt<B></B></FONT>    <TH NOWRAP><FONT COLOR="#363636"><B>AS belegt<B></B></FONT> <TH NOWRAP><FONT COLOR="#363636"><B>JS belegt<B></B></FONT> <TH NOWRAP><FONT COLOR="#363636"><B>Umr. JS belegt<B></B></FONT>    <TH NOWRAP><FONT COLOR="#363636"><B>Umr. Sauen belegt<B></B></FONT> <TH NOWRAP><FONT COLOR="#363636"><B>Intervall Absetzen - Belegen<B></B></FONT>  <TH NOWRAP><FONT COLOR="#363636"><B>% Umr. belegt<B></B></FONT> <TH NOWRAP><FONT COLOR="#363636"><B>Tr&auml;cht. % <B></B></FONT>   <TH NOWRAP><FONT COLOR="#363636"><B>Anz. tragend<B></B></FONT>  <TH NOWRAP><FONT COLOR="#363636"><B>Anz. Belegung
&gt;= 3<B></B></FONT>
<TR BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5" ALIGN=CENTER> <TD ALIGN=LEFT BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><B>&Oslash;<B></B> <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><B>83<B></B>  <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><B>62<B></B>  <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><B>15<B></B>  <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><B>2<B></B>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><B>4<B></B>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><B>4,7<B></B> <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><B>7<B></B>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5">&nbsp <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5">&nbsp <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><B>0<B></B>
<TR BGCOLOR="#ffffff" ALIGN=CENTER> <TD ALIGN=LEFT BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">2020/34</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">94</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">69</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">14</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">4</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">7</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">4,4</FONT>  <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">12</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">100</FONT>  <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">94</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">0</FONT>
<TR BGCOLOR="#ffffff" ALIGN=CENTER> <TD ALIGN=LEFT BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">2020/33</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">78</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">59</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">11</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">2</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">6</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">5,3</FONT>  <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">10</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">100</FONT>  <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">78</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">0</FONT>
<TR BGCOLOR="#ffffff" ALIGN=CENTER> <TD ALIGN=LEFT BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">2020/32</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">74</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">64</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">6</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">2</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">2</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">4,9</FONT>  <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">5</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">100</FONT>  <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">74</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">0</FONT>
<TR BGCOLOR="#ffffff" ALIGN=CENTER> <TD ALIGN=LEFT BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">2020/31</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">85</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">64</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">16</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">1</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">4</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">4,7</FONT>  <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">6</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">92</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">78</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">0</FONT>
<TR BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5" ALIGN=CENTER> <TD ALIGN=LEFT BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">2020/30</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">93</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">65</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">22</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">3</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">3</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">4,6</FONT>  <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">6</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">90</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">84</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">0</FONT>
<TR BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5" ALIGN=CENTER> <TD ALIGN=LEFT BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">2020/29</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">77</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">64</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">10</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">1</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">2</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">4,7</FONT>  <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">4</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">90</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">69</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">0</FONT>
<TR BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5" ALIGN=CENTER> <TD ALIGN=LEFT BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">2020/28</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">93</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">69</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">19</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">2</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">3</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">4,3</FONT>  <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">5</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">87</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">81</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">2</FONT>
<TR BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5" ALIGN=CENTER> <TD ALIGN=LEFT BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">2020/27</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">77</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">55</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">16</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">1</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">5</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">4,8</FONT>  <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">8</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">92</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">71</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">0</FONT>
<TR BGCOLOR="#ffffff" ALIGN=CENTER> <TD ALIGN=LEFT BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">2020/26</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">74</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">63</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">9</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">1</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">1</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">4,6</FONT>  <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">3</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">84</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">62</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">1</FONT>
<TR BGCOLOR="#ffffff" ALIGN=CENTER> <TD ALIGN=LEFT BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">2020/25</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">79</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">55</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">22</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">1</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">1</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">4,9</FONT>  <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">3</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">94</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">74</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">0</FONT>
<TR BGCOLOR="#ffffff" ALIGN=CENTER> <TD ALIGN=LEFT BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">2020/24</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">89</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">68</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">13</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">2</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">6</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">4,2</FONT>  <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">9</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">94</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">84</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">2</FONT>
<TR BGCOLOR="#ffffff" ALIGN=CENTER> <TD ALIGN=LEFT BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">2020/23</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">85</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">63</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">11</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">4</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">7</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">5,6</FONT>  <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">13</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">98</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#363636">83</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#ffffff"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">0</FONT>
<TR BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5" ALIGN=CENTER> <TD ALIGN=LEFT BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">2020/22</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">83</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">53</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">26</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">0</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">4</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">4,3</FONT>  <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">5</FONT>    <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">90</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#363636">75</FONT>   <TD BGCOLOR="#f5f5f5"><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">0</FONT></TABLE>
<BR>
<!--Selection Status Comment -->
<TABLE BORDER=1 CELLSPACING=0 BorderColor="white" CELLPADDING=0 CLASS="currentsel">
<TR><TD ><B>No selections</B></TR>
</TABLE>
<!--EndFragment-->

</BODY>
</HTML>```
````

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to remove attributes on the `table` (not any children) then

```cs
var table = document.QuerySelector("table");
var attributes = table.Attributes.Select(m => m.Name).ToArray();

foreach (var attr in attributes)
{
    table.RemoveAttribute(attr);
}
```

If you also want to get all the children and remove their attributes, then I'd say using `table.QuerySelectorAll("*")` for getting all descendants + applying the same code as above with the `RemoveAttribute` would do the job.